# ValueError: `mask_length` has to be smaller than `sequence_length`, but got `mask_length`: 10 and `sequence_length`: 4` when finetuning wav2vec2.0

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, speech-recognition, huggingface-transformers

I'm getting a value error when i run **trainer.train()**

**for the training, I'm following this notebook** https://www.kaggle.com/code/ajax0564/wave2vec2-0-fine-tuning-english
I'm downloaded the notebook and using it on dataspell since Google collab giving me troubles when i load my dataset.

[image]

and I'm using this modle to fine tune **wav2vec2-base-mine/**  . as datasets I use my own custom made audio dataset and that contains .wav files and their texts in a csv I have done all the pre processing. I'm wondering if there are any solutions for this since i'm struggling in this step for a while now, perhaps if there is a way to edit **mask_length** or something but I don't see it.

The traceback is below,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14780\49973641.py in <module>
----> 1 trainer.train()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1541             self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1542         )
-> 1543         return inner_training_loop(
   1544             args=args,
   1545             resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1789                         tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1790                 else:
-> 1791                     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1792 
   1793                 if (

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2537 
   2538         with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2539             loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2540 
   2541         if self.args.n_gpu > 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2569         else:
   2570             labels = None
-> 2571         outputs = model(**inputs)
   2572         # Save past state if it exists
   2573         # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\wav2vec2\modeling_wav2vec2.py in forward(self, input_values, attention_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict, labels)
   1678         return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
   1679 
-> 1680         outputs = self.wav2vec2(
   1681             input_values,
   1682             attention_mask=attention_mask,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\wav2vec2\modeling_wav2vec2.py in forward(self, input_values, attention_mask, mask_time_indices, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1309 
   1310         hidden_states, extract_features = self.feature_projection(extract_features)
-> 1311         hidden_states = self._mask_hidden_states(
   1312             hidden_states, mask_time_indices=mask_time_indices, attention_mask=attention_mask
   1313         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\wav2vec2\modeling_wav2vec2.py in _mask_hidden_states(self, hidden_states, mask_time_indices, attention_mask)
   1252             hidden_states[mask_time_indices] = self.masked_spec_embed.to(hidden_states.dtype)
   1253         elif self.config.mask_time_prob > 0 and self.training:
-> 1254             mask_time_indices = _compute_mask_indices(
   1255                 (batch_size, sequence_length),
   1256                 mask_prob=self.config.mask_time_prob,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\wav2vec2\modeling_wav2vec2.py in _compute_mask_indices(shape, mask_prob, mask_length, attention_mask, min_masks)
    161 
    162     if mask_length > sequence_length:
--> 163         raise ValueError(
    164             f"`mask_length` has to be smaller than `sequence_length`, but got `mask_length`: {mask_length}"
    165             f" and `sequence_length`: {sequence_length}`"

ValueError: `mask_length` has to be smaller than `sequence_length`, but got `mask_length`: 10 and `sequence_length`: 4`
```

Answer (score 0):

The mask_length parameter comes from the configuration JSON of wav2vec2-base. I think you will have to edit the configuration of the model prior to loading then load from your edited config.

My guess is you will have to edit possibly several of these to 4.

```
 "mask_channel_length": 10,
  "mask_channel_min_space": 1,
  "mask_channel_other": 0.0,
  "mask_channel_prob": 0.0,
  "mask_channel_selection": "static",
  "mask_feature_length": 10,
  "mask_feature_prob": 0.0,
  "mask_time_length": 10,
  "mask_time_min_space": 1,
  "mask_time_other": 0.0,
  "mask_time_prob": 0.05,
```

So you will have to copy all the files from [here](https://huggingface.co/facebook/wav2vec2-base/). Then change the [config](https://huggingface.co/facebook/wav2vec2-base/blob/main/config.json) save it then finally [load it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71561761/how-to-load-a-fine-tuned-pytorch-huggingface-bert-model-from-a-checkpoint-file) from your local directory. You may run into some other errors as well as your data seems to be a differing length than the one the model was trained on. So you may need to correct those parts of the JSON config file as well.

Comment: Well I was aware og this config.JSON file when i searched this through internet but it seems that **I don't have that file in the wav2vec2-base folder** . I don't know if i'm doing something wrong, I just realized that my **wav2vec2-base is only 107 KB**. This is a **snippet** of the wav2vec2-base folder [link](https://ibb.co/QdyYS3C) can you take a look?

Comment: What is in the preprocessor_config file?